# general solutions to differential equations of first order

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, solution-verification

general solution to differential equations:

$$\frac{dy}{dx}+e^{2x}y^2=0$$

$$\frac{dy}{dx}= -e^{2x}y^2$$

$$\int \frac{1}{y^2} dy= \int -e^{2x} dx+c$$

$$-\frac{1}{y}= -0.5\ e^{2x}+c$$

$$y= 2e^{-2x}+c $$

Is this correct?

Comment: You can substitute your solution into the ODE and verify if it is correct.

Comment: whats that ODE? sorry

Comment: ODE = Ordinary Differential Equation

Comment: To clarify Amzoti's advice - You can take your solution y=stuff and then plug it into the differential equation you're trying to solve. If your solution is correct the equality will hold. If your solution is incorrect, the equality will not hold. So, simply take the derivative of your solution to sub in for $\frac{dy}{dx}$ etc. and verify that doing this causes the LHS and RHS to be equal.

Answer (score 0):

Be careful,

$$\frac{dy}{dx}+e^{2x}y^2=0$$

$$ \Longleftrightarrow \frac{dy}{dx}= -e^{2x}y^2$$

$$\Longleftrightarrow \int \frac{1}{y^2} dy= \int -e^{2x} dx$$

Why do you put a constant c in your integration? The constant comes by integrating, I mean after the integration is completed, not before.

$$\Longleftrightarrow -\frac{1}{y}= -0.5\ e^{2x}+c_{0}$$

$$\Longleftrightarrow \frac{1}{y}= 0.5\ e^{2x}+c_{1}$$

with $$ c_{1} = -c_{0} $$

Finally,

$$\Longleftrightarrow {y}= \frac{2}{e^{2x}+c_{1}}$$